# How to define up- and downstream dependencies between multibranch-pipeline-jobs in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, branch

In the past I used only freestyle jobs in jenkins. I used the [Build Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-pipeline-plugin/) plugin to visualize the up- and downstream dependencies. This was a great feature and it was easy to understand the dependencies between the jobs.

Now I started using several Multibranch-Pipline-Jobs which is a much better choice for my jobs. But I wonder **how can I define and visualize up- and downstream dependencies?**

Comment: I found this Question, which is similar but not the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913295/visualize-jenkins-pipeline-or-multibranch-pipeline-jobs?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's late, but I solved it by adding this step to Jenkinsfile.

```
    stage('trigger') {
        steps {
            script {
                def jobName = env.JOB_NAME.replaceFirst("currentJob", "nextJob")
                build job: jobName, wait: false
            }
        }
    }
```

In my case, the urls are:
/branches/1.0/currentJob
/branches/1.0/nextJob

Comment: Wow, thank you. I cannot test this right now, but it looks really what I was searching for!